# Explanation for email pattern

Tags: java, android

I got email pattern in different types from google and SO. But i can't understand the pattern .Please anybody give me an explanation for the following pattern. Thank in advance.

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
                  "\\@" +
                  "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
                  "(" +
                  "\\." +
                  "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
                  ")+"
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, this regex is wrong. It'll allow a lot of clearly invalid email addresses (like "a@test.c-"), plus things that are at least somewhat odd (like "a+b@test.com").

According to the spec at least, I think that a+b@test.com is technically valid, but the full spec is rarely actually implemented, so it's a design decision whether you want to allow something like that. (Note that some major vendors *do* allow emails like that).

Try to break it down into components. The full Regex string is as follows:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\+\.\_\%\-\+]{1,256}\@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,64}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,25})+
```

The following string:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\+\.\_\%\-\+]{1,256}
```

matches characters before the "@" symbol.

The

```
{1,256}
```

part means "match the proceeding item between 1 and 256 times." In other words, there's at least 1 character (but no more than 256) before the "@" symbol. For example,

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1, 50}
```

means "between 1 and 50 alphanumeric characters."

\@
matches the "@" symbol.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,64}
```

At least one alphanumeric character followed by 0 - 64 alphanumeric characters (or dashes) after the @ symbol and before the "." (i.e. before the ".com" or whatever part). Recall that `{0, 64}` means "between 0 and 64 matches."

```
(\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,25})+
```

The part after the "." (e.g. ".com"). Includes a period followed by between 1 and 26 alphanumeric characters. It also allows a - after the first alphanumeric character.

The obvious flaw here is that there are few constraints in where (or how many) dashes occur. For example, the following email addresses are all "valid":

```
a+b@test.c--------a

a+b@test.c-

a+.%b@test.c

%@t.c-
```

Comment: what is the use of {1,256},{0,64}.

Comment: @Daryl I edited to mention those as well - {1, 256} means "between 1 and 256 matches for the proceeding item" and "{0, 64}" means "between 0 and 64 matches for the proceeding item."

Comment: thanks alot for spending your valuable time for clarified my doubt.Now i understanded very well.

Comment: @chrylis According to the spec, yes, I think that's technically permitted, but it seems like it's rarely implemented by email providers and whatnot, so I assume if someone tried to enter something like this it was a mistake on their part.

Comment: It's used *all the time* with Gmail. Forms that block the plus sign really tick me off.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it down part by part:

`[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}` - matches a string which can contain a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9 and the characters "+", ".", "_", "%", "-". The string can be between 1 and 256 characters long. (why the + symbol twice, I don't know)

`\\@` - matches the @ symbol in the email address

`[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}` - matches the first part after the @ symbol which starts with a character that is one of a-Z, A-Z or 0-9, followed by characters that can also contain a hyphen('-'). E.g. 'stack-overflow'. This string can be 1 to 65 characters long(including the first character)

`\\.` - matches the . itself (the . in google.com)

`[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}` - matches a similar string as the above, which can be upto 25 characters long

The entire part after the . is enclosed in ()+, to indicate that this can repeat as many times as needed (e.g. mymachine.mydepartment.mycompany.com)

An example that uses most of the pattern is

```
user%21@my-jobs.my-company.com
```